# Azure Devops cannot locate file in nuget package when building using Linux Build

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, code-analysis

Our company uses a nuget package to distribute the Stylecop ruleset.  This nuget package has a props file which I have modified to look like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <LinuxWarningFile>~/.nuget/packages/ourcompany.rulesets/0.0.0.0/content/OurCompanyRulesAsWarning.ruleset</LinuxWarningFile>
    <IsLinux Condition = "Exists($(LinuxWarningFile))">true</IsLinux>
    <IsLinux Condition = "$(IsLinux) == ''">false</IsLinux>

    <IsWindows Condition = "$(IsLinux) == false">true</IsWindows>
    <IsWindows Condition = "$(IsLinux) == true">false</IsWindows>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And '$(IsLinux)'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>~/.nuget/packages/ourcompany.rulesets/0.0.0.0/content/OurCompanyRulesAsWarning.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And '$(IsWindows)'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\ourcompany.rulesets\0.0.0.0\content\OurCompanyRulesAsWarning.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' And '$(IsLinux)'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>~/.nuget/packages/ourcompany.rulesets/0.0.0.0/content/OurCompanyRulesAsError.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' And '$(IsWindows)'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\ourcompany.rulesets\0.0.0.0\content\OurCompanyRulesAsError.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

(Obviously during package creation the versioning is corrected and this is all working perfectly).

On Azure Devops:

- It finds the correct ruleset when the Pool is set to Windows Build.
- It cannot find the ruleset when the Pool is set to Linux Build.

The error: Warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file ".nuget\packages\ourcompany.rulesets\1.0.20230.1\content\OurCompanyRulesAsError.ruleset".

given that it is leaving out the ~, i think that it has not found the file at the path given in the first logical block, has evaluated IsLinux to false and IsWindows to true and is using the path that includes the UserProfile which does not exist on the linux build.

From examining this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file), I think the default paths for the nuget packages are:

`The location of the default global packages folder. The default is %userprofile%\.nuget\packages (Windows) or ~/.nuget/packages (Mac/Linux).`

How can I fix the props file so that it can find the rulesets for a Linux build please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the MSBuildThisFileDirectory property to avoid having to find the path? If the .props file and .ruleset files are in the same package you can use MSBuildThisFileDirectory and a relative path.

Assuming the .props file is also in a sub-directory of the package (.ruleset looks to be in a content subdirectory):

````
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/../content/OurCompanyRulesAsWarning.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/../content/OurCompanyRulesAsError.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>```
````

Comment: that absolutely worked.  the MSBuildThisFileDirectory let me form a relative path to the ruleset!  Thank you!